# Android Map activity using longitude and latitude

Tags: android, google-maps-mobile

I want to draw a map inside of my application using longitude and latitude. Is this possible in android?

I could only find [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) in developer's docs

If you could shed some light on this it would be a great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for something that does everything you want plus more -- it actually searches for a location by name, converts it to lat / long and then maps it:
https://github.com/bricolsoftconsulting/GeocoderPlusExample